Trigger @Defer and @placeholder blocks multiple times
Let's say I have the following blocks :
@defer (onSignal()) {
  if (succesOnRetrievingAsyncData()) {
    <succes-component />
  } else {
     <error-component />
     <button click="retryAsyncCall()"> Retry </button>
  }
  
} @placeholder(minimum 1s) {
  <img src="placeholder.png" />
}

As it is mentioned in the following doc : https://angular.dev/guide/defer#triggers

If the when condition switches back to false, the defer block is not reverted back to the placeholder. The swap is a one-time operation. If the content within the block should be conditionally rendered, an if condition can be used within the block itself

I would like to perform again the async call when user clicks on the button, and trigger the @defer/@placeholder blocks to show the placeholder image.
How can I achieve that ?

Defer is not the right tool for that. Deferable views are meant to lazy loading components it's not like react's suspense

To my knowledge defer only runs once, you have to wrap another if condition to handle all subsequent cases!
@defer (on idle; when onSignal()) {
  @if (onSignal()) {
    @if (succesOnRetrievingAsyncData()) {
      <div>success</div>
    } @else {
      <div>error</div>
      <button (click)="retryAsyncCall()"> Retry </button>
    }
  } @else {
  <img src="placeholder.png" />
  }
      
} @placeholder(minimum 1s) {
  <img src="placeholder.png" />
}

Full Code:
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    @defer (on idle; when onSignal()) {
      @if (onSignal()) {
        @if (succesOnRetrievingAsyncData()) {
          <div>success</div>
        } @else {
          <div>error</div>
          <button (click)="retryAsyncCall()"> Retry </button>
        }
      } @else {
      <img src="placeholder.png" />
      }
      
    } @placeholder(minimum 1s) {
      <img src="placeholder.png" />
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  retry = false;
  onSignal = signal(false);

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onSignal.set(true);
    }, 3000);
  }

  retryAsyncCall() {
    this.onSignal.set(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onSignal.set(true);
    }, 5000);
  }

  succesOnRetrievingAsyncData() {
    return this.retry;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

You can also get rid of the defer completely and just use the if condition to achieve what you want. If that is what you need.
  @if (onSignal()) {
    @if (succesOnRetrievingAsyncData()) {
      <div>success</div>
    } @else {
      <div>error</div>
      <button (click)="retryAsyncCall()"> Retry </button>
    }
  } @else {
    <img src="placeholder.png" />
  }

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for you answer, but i'm loosing the "minimum 1s" on the @placeholder the second time

@isy seems like a lot of work? does it have to be done? You can just set onSignal.set(false) on the beginning of retryAsyncCall, then below that setTimeout(() => { onSignal.set(true); }, 1000); will do the same thing, with the least code complexity, inside the set timeout you need to trigger the api call and then set the signal!
